# jquery array checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var others = $("#6");
others.click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    $("#6").attr('checked',true);
});
```

I have an array of check boxes which is drawn from database. I want to uncheck other check boxes when a certain check box is ticked in my case checkbox with id #6, and it uncheck a checkbox #6 if other checkbox is check.

The code above is able to uncheck other checkbox but how can I uncheck the checkbox with id 6,once the other checkbox is check.

Comment: "6" is not a valid ID for an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if(this.id == '6' && this.checked)
        $('input:checkbox:not(#6)').attr('checked', false);
    else
        $('#6').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Haha getting rep is a good motivation :P (Besides that, SO is a nice timesink during boring lectures. :D)